# Amount of lines of a 2D Char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Is there a posibility to calculate the lines of a 2d `char` array?

**Context:**

I've read names out of a csv file and i want to calculate with the numbers behind it.

**Pseudocode:**

```
int workers = size of the 2d char array (a_name)
```

`workers = sizeof(a_name)` is obviously not working.

Comment: Maybe you want `sizeof(a_name) / sizeof(*a_name)`?

Comment: If you read the file, it should have been very easy to keep track of the number of lines, and also *necessary* (how did you otherwise keep track of where in the array you would write each line?)

Comment: Please show your declaration for `a_name` and the part of your code where you create its context.

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the file?

Comment: Thats not really what i mean, its more like: how many lines are filled with the read csv data.

Comment: And I'm saying that if you read the lines from the file in the program, then you already *know* the number of lines you have read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** you can count the number of workers while reading the csv file.

**2.** you can let write a function that will count the number of workers ( depends on the number of worker you're expecting it might be worth it ).
anyway if you're gonna use strlen - it's gonna run over the entire thing till it reaches the first '\0'.

it should look something like this

```
char workers[ MAX_WORKERS ][ MAX_NAME_LENGTH ];
int counter;

// assuming the array was filled from 0 sequntially
for ( counter = 0; counter < MAX_WORKERS; counter++ ) {
    if ( *(workers[ i ]) == 0 )
         break;
}

// counter now holds the number of workers
```

another possible solution ( not sure if I'm doing this right )

```
char workers[ MAX_WORKERS ][ MAX_NAME_LENGTH ];
char *pointer;
int counter

counter = 0;
pointer = workers;

// assuming a memset or calloc have been made for workers, and that the array was filled from 0 sequntially
while( pointer != NULL ) {
    pointer += MAX_NAME_LENGTH;
    counter++;
}

// counter now holds the number of workers
```

Comment: I think you should empathize more on the point that the code will only work if all `MAX_WORKERS` entries were used.